# multiple forms target clicked button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to have a comment form for each image on a page. The number of images are dynamic. Is there a way for jquery to target the form data for the submit button that was clicked?

I currently have:

```
$('.comment_button').click(function() {    
var comment = $('input#comment').val();
    var id = $('input#id').val();
    var other = $('input#other').val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&id=' + id + '&other=' + other;

    alert (dataString);
});
```

Which means all the form fields and form names are the same for each image (probably should make them unique for validation) but regardless is there a way to get the form fields for when a user clicked a certain submit button in that particular form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your problem I understand,
You can use `serialize` function for that
 like

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  return false;
```

});

Documentation here [JquerySerialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a container div for the comment form. So up on clicking find the parent div for the button. Then find all the input elements in that div, which will give the input textboxes for that comment form.

A sample pseudo code.. Try like this..

```
$('.comment_button').click(function() {    

  var parentDiv= $(this).parent();
  $(parentDiv "input[type=text]").each(function()
  {
    if(this.id == "comment")
      //get comment text
   .
   .

  });
});
```